# ¿Como modificar datos en array resultado de consulta a BD?

Tags: php

Trato de modificar uno de los datos del `array` que obtengo de una consulta a `BD`,antes de pasarlo a `JSON`, pero no lo consigo, accedo al valor en un `foreach` pero no sé como cambiar el dato.

> array(1) { ["data"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(8) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["customer_name"]=> string(8) "Cristina" ["customer_surname1"]=> string(9) "Martínez" ["customer_surname2"]=> string(10) "Fernández" ["born_date"]=> string(10) "1980-03-02" ["wish"]=> string(1) "1" ["type"]=> string(7) "Estudio" ["start"]=> string(19) "2017-12-19 17:00:00" } [1]=> array(8) { ["id"]=> string(2) "78" ["customer_name"]=> string(8) "Héctor " ["customer_surname1"]=> string(6) "Arraiz" ["customer_surname2"]=> string(4) "Algo" ["born_date"]=> string(10) "1985-11-10" ["wish"]=> string(1) "1" ["type"]=> string(8) "Exterior" ["start"]=> string(19) "2017-12-21 17:00:00" } } }

```
$sql = "SELECT customers.id,`customer_name`,`customer_surname1`,`customer_surname2`,`born_date`,`wish`, type_event.type, events.start FROM `customers` INNER JOIN event_has_customers on customers.id = customer_id left JOIN events on event_id = events.id LEFT JOIN type_event on events.id = type_event.id";


    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if($mysqli->errno) die($mysqli->error);
    $response["data"]=array();
    while($registros = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $response["data"][]=$registros;
    }

    //aquí llego a la fecha
    foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            var_dump(formatDte($v['start']));//aquí cambia el formato
        }
    }

echo json_encode($response);//start sigue en su formato original

function formatDte($cdn){
    $array = explode(' ', $cdn);
    return $array[0];
}
```

Comment: Prueba con algo como esto: `$value[$k]['start']  = formatDte($v['start']);` o bien con esto: `$value[$k]['start']  = formatDte($value[$k]['start']);`. Si es posible pon un ejemplo de cómo es tu array, quizá haya soluciones mejores...

Comment: Tampoco funcionó. Edito pregunta para mostrar var_dump de $response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no estas "*pisando*" el valor en el arreglo `$response`.

### Solución 1

Sobreescribir el valor en la posición

```
// aquí llego a la fecha
foreach($response as $key => $value) {
  foreach($value as $k => $v) {

    // AQUI cambia el formato y guardamos en la posición correspondiente
    // del arreglo $response
    $response[$key][$k]['start'] = formatDte($v['start']);
  }
}
```

### Solución 2

Hacer uso de [valores por referencia](http://php.net/manual/es/language.references.whatdo.php) para pisar el valor de la variable.

```
// aquí llego a la fecha
foreach($response as $key => &$value) {
  foreach($value as $k => &$v) {

    // AQUI cambia el formato y escribimos en $v que apunta a la posicion
    // $response[$key][$k]['start']
    $v['start'] = formatDte($v['start']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Al fin! Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta asignandole el resultado de la funcion `formatDte()`:

```
 foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            // modificamos el indice start por el nuevo formato
            $v['start'] = formatDte($v['start'])
        }
    }
```

Comment: ya lo hicé pero no resulta.

Answer (score 0):

no se si te he entendido bien, pero si lo que estas tratando es de transformar la fecha de formato canónico a otro formato yo probaría haciendo esto

`function formatDte($cdn){
   $date = new DateTime($cdn);//esto recibe un formato en string '2000-01-01'
   return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');// esto es une ejemplo visita la docu
}`
http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

El valor de ese return  lo pones como valor en el indice que necesites, pero si ya tienes un array asociativo y sabes el valor del indice no es necesario que lo recorras entero para solo cambiar un valor.

Comment: Hola Pedro, si, quiero cambiar el formato de la fecha, el problema es que no soy capaz de hacerlo en el array $response. $response es la ejecución de una consulta a BD que devuleve varios registros, por eso entiendo que debo recorrer el array para modificar la fecha en cada uno de ellos y luego convertirlo a JSON

Comment: Perfecto, ahora si te entiendo bien, es correcto debes de recorrer cada array. En tal caso cuando ya tienes localizada tu fecha solo tiene que aplicar tu función y probando lo que te propongo para de esta forma cambiar el valor de la fecha que tienes en ese array por la fecha transformada.

Comment: ya probé, y por supuesto funciona pero no cambio losel valor de 'start', cuando creo el JSON de $response 'start' sigue en su formato original